# Creating Store Clock Function - Open/Close & Events depending on time

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, clock

So I have a code that is functioning properly. I received some help putting this together because despite feeling reasonably confident in my coding skills (fairly new) - time avoids me, I find it confusing to determine how it works in PHP.

I am looking to create a function that acts as my stores clock and returns "open" - "closed" - "1 hour to close" results that I can use in other functions.

For example:

```
if ( store_clock() == 'open' ) {
     echo 'Open';
}
elseif ( store_clock() == '1_hr_left' ) {
     echo 'You have 27 mins and 12 secs to place an order' );
else {
     echo 'Sorry, we are closed.';
}
```

I currently have the following code which works correctly in regard to closing times, properly displaying the time left countdown etc. The issue being I don't have my open times, and I would prefer to split the code up - allowing me to use the `store_clock()` function to trigger other events throughout the site... not just the closing counter.

To do this I am assuming I would need 2 to 3 different functions, rather than just the 1... however I am feeling very confused. Any help appreciated. (PS. `get_field()` is calling ACF values)

```
function sat_clock() {

    $the_time = current_time('timestamp');
    $exact_time = gmdate('g:ia', $the_time);
    $weekday_close = get_field('weekday_close', 'options');
    $sat_close = get_field('sat_close', 'options');
    $sun_close = get_field('sun_close', 'options');

    // Set your closing times here from sun-sat
    $closing_times = array( $sun_close, $weekday_close, $weekday_close, $weekday_close, $weekday_close, '7:31 pm', $sat_close );

    if ( $closing_times[date( 'w', current_time('timestamp') )] !== false ) {
        $closing_time = strtotime( sprintf( '%s %s', date( 'd F Y', current_time('timestamp') ), $closing_times[date( 'w', current_time('timestamp') )] ) );
        if ( $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') > 0 && $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') < 1800 ) {
            echo '<strong>LAST CALL</strong><p class="m-0" id="closing-soon-timer"></p>';
            ?>
            <script>
                var timeLeft = <?php echo $closing_time - current_time('timestamp'); ?>;
                // Update the count down every 1 second
                var x = setInterval(function() {

                  // Time calculations for minutes and seconds
                  var minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
                  var seconds = Math.floor(timeLeft % 60);

                  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
                  document.getElementById("closing-soon-timer").innerHTML = "You have <strong>" + minutes + "</strong> minutes " + "<strong>" + seconds + "</strong> seconds to place an order.";

                  // If the count down is finished, write some text
                  if (timeLeft < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("closing-soon-timer").innerHTML = "Closed for today";
                  }
                  timeLeft--;
                }, 1000);
            </script>
            <?php
        } elseif  ( $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') < 0 ) {
            echo "<p>Closed for today</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Opened</p>" . gmdate('g:ia', $closing_time);
            var_dump($exact_time);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>Closed for today</p>";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'sat_clock' );
```